# Separate One Column Into Two Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

I'm trying to separate one column that contains a blood type into two columns.

For example, if my value is `ABNG` in the existing blood type column, I want to separate this into two new columns and insert the values: `AB` and `Neg`.

Not sure if a case statement will handle this, but I tried different variations and could not find a solution.

Here is what the existing data looks like, there are 9 blood types (including the Unknown which is fine) with some bad data mixed in (' ', 0, and B).

[image: Blood Types]

Without having the best grasp on how to handle this I am thinking a view could be created that would split the information into new columns.

And this is what I'm hoping the end result to be:

[image: Desired Results]

Is this possible?

Comment: Hard to say wihout any data sample. Maybe try to use SUBSTRING or LEFT/RIGHT functions, or CHARINDEX/PATINDEX to determine where to cut your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement for checking conditions and `wildcard` characters for string filtration for the source column.

```
SELECT PBTYPE [Existing Blood Type],
CASE 
    WHEN PBTYPE LIKE 'O%'  THEN 'O'
    WHEN LEFT(PBTYPE,1)='A' AND SUBSTRING(PBTYPE,2,1)<>'B' THEN 'A'
    WHEN LEFT(PBTYPE,2)='AB' AND SUBSTRING(PBTYPE,2,1)='B' THEN 'AB'
    WHEN PBTYPE LIKE 'B%'  THEN 'B'
    WHEN PBTYPE = 'UNK'    THEN 'UNK'
END [Blood Type],
CASE 
    WHEN PBTYPE LIKE '%POS' OR PBTYPE LIKE '%PS' THEN 'POS' 
    WHEN PBTYPE LIKE '%NEG' OR PBTYPE LIKE '%NG' THEN 'NEG' 
    WHEN PBTYPE LIKE '%B' THEN 'B' 
    WHEN PBTYPE LIKE '%UNK' THEN 'UNK'
END [Rho]
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE PBTYPE <> '' AND PBTYPE <> '0'
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281047/split-column-to-multiple-column) to view result**

Answer (score 0):

Given that there's a limited number of blood types (and hoping that your data is formatted well), you could do something like:

```
SELECT Type = CASE WHEN col LIKE 'AB%' THEN 'AB' /*gets AB*/
ELSE LEFT(col, 1)  /*gets o,a,or b*/ END, 
Valence = RIGHT(col, 3) /*gets pos or neg*/
```